# Postgresql server to server replication

Tags: postgresql, psql, database-replication, pg-dump, pg-restore

Say I have two remote servers 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. In both the servers I have postgresql database installed with the same databases. Now what I need is, whatever changes or alterations that are done to the database on server 10.0.0.1 should automatically be replicated to the database on server 10.0.0.2.Is there any way to do this automation process? If So, Please suggest me the best and most efficient way of doing this. The version of postgresql I am using is 9.5.3.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article by Digital Ocean seems to describe every step well enough — [how to setup master slave replication on postgresql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-on-postgresql-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)